# Read a tab delimited file into a dictionary in python without using CSV module

Tags: python, text-files, csv

I have to use this text `sfs.gff` to make a dictionary and then make a dictionary of dictionaries and I am not really sure how to go about it

This is the text

[image]
This is what I have so far, just not sure what to do next.

```
import sys
import textwrap

with open(sys.argv[1]) as gff:
    info = dict()
```

Comment: Can you desribe what is the problem, why aren't you geting a satisfactory output

Comment: Can you give a sample of the output you expect? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Why "without using csv module" ???

Comment: Please don't post code or testdata as image.